# database table creating error in android

Tags: android, sqlite

This code i write in m registr activity but it give me error ANR and not generating the database

this code on the register button

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("RoseDetails",MODE_APPEND, null);
    //          db.execSQL("create table if not exists table_register(firstname VARCHAR(20),lastname VARCHAR(20),emailaddress VARCHAR(20),gender VARCHAR(20),password VARCHAR(20),confirmpassword VARCHAR(20)");
    //          db.execSQL("INSERT into table_student values('"+firstname.getText()+"','"+lastname.getText()+"','"+emailid.getText()+"','"+gendervaule+"','"+Pwd.getText()+"','"+"','"+cpwd.getText()+"')");
    //          Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table_register" , null);
    //          while(c.moveToNext())
    //          {   
    //          if(c.moveToFirst())
    //          {
    //              String fn=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("firstname"));
    //              String ln=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lastname"));
    //              String add=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("emailaddress"));
    //              String g=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("gender"));
    //              String p1=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("password"));
    //              String p2=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("confirmpassword"));
    //              Toast.makeText(this,"firstname"+fn+"\t"+"lastname"+ln+"\t"+"emailid"+add+"\t"+"gender"+g+"\t"+"pass"+p1+"\t"+"cpwd"+p2,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //          }
    //          } 
    //          c.close();
    //          db.close();
```

**logcat error**

```
11-24 08:01:00.163: W/dalvikvm(278): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
11-24 08:01:00.193: E/AndroidRuntime(278): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-24 08:01:00.193: E/AndroidRuntime(278): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error: create table if not exists table_register(firstname VARCHAR(20),lastname VARCHAR(20),emailaddress VARCHAR(20),gender VARCHAR(20),password VARCHAR(20),confirmpassword VARCHAR(20)
11-24 08:01:00.193: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
11-24 08:01:00.193: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1727)
11-24 08:01:00.193: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.example.orderplacemnet.Registration_Page.onClick(Registration_Page.java:158)
11-24 08:01:00.193: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
11-24 08:01:00.193: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
11-24 08:01:00.193: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-24 08:01:00.193: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-24 08:01:00.193: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-24 08:01:00.193: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-24 08:01:00.193: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 08:01:00.193: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-24 08:01:00.193: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-24 08:01:00.193: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-24 08:01:00.193: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what's the error? show the logcat

Comment: what are you trying to do with while loop and if condition.. it looks like this could create a infinite loop..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the closing parenthesis in this line at the end

```
 db.execSQL("create table if not exists table_register(firstname VARCHAR(20),lastname VARCHAR(20),emailaddress VARCHAR(20),gender VARCHAR(20),password VARCHAR(20),confirmpassword VARCHAR(20)");
```

it should be

```
  db.execSQL("create table if not exists table_register(firstname VARCHAR(20),lastname VARCHAR(20),emailaddress VARCHAR(20),gender VARCHAR(20),password VARCHAR(20),confirmpassword VARCHAR(20))");
```

Comment: loool, if I hit that damn enter 1 min before . I had to go and grab a glass of water arggg :p

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to execute the query on the SQLITE tool first and then to put in the code. It will prevent the syntax errors of any type.